# Expo-cli ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: react-native, expo

I installed expo-cli 5.4.10 (node v16.14.0) after which i execute the command

```
yarn start
```

I go to the browser and see this error in the console **ReferenceError: process is not defined**

looking for several solutions such as (https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-referenceerror-process-not-defined)

I have tried the following

```
npm install react-scripts@latest
npm install --save-dev react-error-overlay@6.0.9
```

package.json

```
"resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
}
```

but this does not solve my problem in any way, perhaps someone has come across a similar one and is ready to help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had same problem today.
Solution: `npm i -g expo-cli@5.4.9`

Answer (score 0):

The web interface from cli is broken in version `5.4.10`.
You can either use it with the terminal only, or use `5.4.8` (`5.4.9` might work, but I haven't tested it yet)